# Delete hplip files after installation

Tags: 16.04

While installing hplip files were downloaded to Downloads folder. I think the files were created while running `make`. Can I delete these files after installation?

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you may.

"Hewlett-Packard Linux Imaging & Printing (HPLIP) is an HP-developed open-source Linux solution for printing, scanning, and faxing with HP inkjet and LaserJet printers." - source http://hplipopensource.com/node/249